# Lua string.gsub text between pattern

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

How would I extract in Lua a text between a pattern. For example

```
s="this is a test string. <!2014-05-03 23:12:08!> something more"
```

1. I would need only the date/time as result:  `2014-05-03 23:12:08`
   `print(string.gsub(s, "%<!.-%!>"))` doesn't work
2. I would need all the text WITHOUT the date/time like: `"this is a
   test string. something more"`

Comment: If you can be sure that no other `<` or `>` occur inside the text; use the `%b` matching: `s:gsub( '%b<>', '' )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern `"<!.-!>"` works, but you need to use `string.match` to get the date/time part:

```
 print(string.match(s, "<!(.-)!>"))
```

Note that you don't need to escape `!` or `<` in a pattern. Of course escaping them is not an error.

To get the string without the date/time part, replace it with an empty string:

```
local result = string.gsub(s, "<!.-!>", "")
print(result)
```

You can also expand the pattern `.-` to validate the format of date/time more:

```
result = string.gsub(s, "<!%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%d%s+%d%d:%d%d:%d%d!>", "")
```

Comment: Amazing one ! =)